# Stopping from getting .apk file after installing application: Android

Tags: android, apk

I have used an application named **ES File Manager**. In this application I found application manager feature by which, we can get an apk file of installed application as a backup. I want to prevent my application's from getting backed up as an .apk file.

Before, I was thinking that this is not possible. I can't prevent my apps from being backed up. But today I found one game, which is not allowing to take backup as an .apk.

I searched a lot to get answer of my query. But I didn't found a single one. Does any one know how can I save my apps?

Comment: Thanks for your response simon. I'm trying to secure my apps.

Comment: You can only make it more difficult.  There are *many* discussions already on StackOverflow.  Just search.  Short answer is, you can't.  Focus on the value of your app and your valued users instead.  The big guys can't stop piracy, you won't be able to either.